# R vetiver load failed

Tags: r, github, package, vetiver

i'm trying to use the vetiver package to write model cards but the library won't load when working from a github repo. Any ideas ?

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘vetiver’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'vetiver', details:
  call: NULL
  error: internal error: dynamic() received unexpected call 'installed_packages(lib.loc = renv_libpaths_system(), priority = priority)'
> R.version.string
[1] "R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15)"
```

Comment: Apologies for this problem! This is due to you having versions of renv and vetiver that don't work together. Can you try updating to the latest CRAN versions for both vetiver and renv? Also, you [can check out this issue](https://github.com/rstudio/vetiver-r/issues/223) for another idea.